# Yocto Warrior Cannot Set Password for root or other users

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I am using the meta-tegra warrior branch layer to build an sd card image for the Nvidia Jetson Nano. The image completes and the board boots, but I cannot log in if I try to set any kind of password in Yocto. I've tried creating users other than root and setting their passwords, but the same problem occurs where I cannot log in.

If I leave "debug-tweaks" enabled, and do not attempt to modify the root password at all, I can successfully log in without a password.

I am using warrior branch for OE and haven't modified other layers. How can I set a password for root?

Here are my local.conf password related lines:

```
# Password Stuff
INHERIT += "extrausers"
#EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES = "debug-tweaks"
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -P mypassword123 root; "
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = " useradd testing; \
                       useradd mts; \
                       usermod  -p 'testing12345' testing; \
                       usermod  -p 'comp12345' comp; \
```

Comment: Remove the second `EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS` as it will overwrite the first one. Have you tried writing a recipe for such a task? Did it work or the result was the very same?

Comment: I think usermod with `-p` (minus p) needs a hash generated from `openssl <passwd>` command?

Comment: Thank you both for the pointers. @Nayfe, it turned out to be the openssl command, to get it to work I had to do this: EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -p $(openssl passwd blahblahblah) root;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`usermod` with `-p` (minus p) needs a hash generated from `openssl passwd` command so you need to set Yocto variable as following:

`EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -p $(openssl passwd <some_password>) root;"`

If you want to append something to bitbake variable, you need to use `_append` or `+=` operators, ie:

```
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS_append = " useradd testing;"
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS_append = " useradd mts;"
...
```